# Logistic growth decreasing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, population-dynamics

In a city, the initial population is
$$P(0)=70281$$
and 10 years after,
$$P(10)=66277$$

I have to find $P(t)$ using the logistic model with max value equal to 80000, which gives the following equation
$$\frac{1}{P}\cdot\frac{dP}{dt}=k\left(1-\frac{P}{80000}\right)$$

When I solved it, I found
$$P(t)=\frac{80000}{1+Ae^{-kt}}$$
and from the inital conditions,
$$A=0.1383,\qquad k=-0.04038$$

Hence,
$$P(t)=\frac{80000}{1+0.1383e^{0.04038t}}$$

My question is: shouldn't $k>0$ and then,
$$P(t)=\frac{80000}{1+0.1383e^{-0.04038t}}?$$

If so, what's wrong?

By the way, I plotted $P(t)$ using Geogebra and it makes sense for me, the population is decreasing. But I don't know if this could happen in the logistic model.

Comment: @Gregory yes,that's my question: why $k<0$?

Comment: I agree, that your question is strange from the sense of what logistic "growth" implies. If you had $\dot P = rP(1 - P/K), P(0) = P_0 < K$ with $r <0$, you would never see this population grow. However, there is nothing mathematically wrong with $r < 0$. You have three parameters in your logistic model, $r, K, P_0$. Your question fixes $K = 8000$ and the other two are implied by your conditions. There is nothing left, despite the oddity of the formulation.

Comment: @Gregory so, everything is ok? Nothing wrong?